# im trying to make a quiz for my bootcamp and i cant figure out what is wrong with the code

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, if-statement

I'm trying to make a quiz game for a class and I can't seem to find the problem.

```
function askQuestions(random) {
    var random = math.floor(math.random() * testQuestions.length);
    var start = document.getElementById(testStart);
    start.addEventListner('click', askQuestions);

    if (start) {
        document.write(random);
    }
    return;
}
```

This is the function and I have an array of objects, which is referenced in the "random" variable. I'm totally lost and I know I'm missing something simple. The purpose of this function is to display a random question from the array `testQuestions`.

Comment: what is the value of `testStart`? should be a string

Comment: `math` doesn't exist - you mean `Math`

Comment: You pass in an array called `random` but you're testing `testQuestions` for length. Your event listener should be outside of the function. What is the `testStart` variable? That's not in your code.

Comment: So there are a bunch of things that look off. It should be `Math.floor` and `Math.random` (uppercase M), does the variable `testStart` contain the id of your clickable element or did you mean to use the string `'testStart'`, what you want to write is probably testQuestions[random], also do you really want to use `document.write(randomQuestion)`? If start is defined, it would erase your whole page and you will only be left with the random question on it. Last,`var start=document.getElementById(testStart);
start.addEventListner('click', askQuestions);` should be outside askQuestions function

Comment: so it seems like i need to capitalize Math, move 'start.addEventListner.getElementById(testStart);' outside of the function, and change the variable being called at the front of the function from 'random' to 'testQuestions', which is the name of the object arrray. is that about right? the variable 'testStart' is supposed to be the id for the start button in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Math is a global object and it starts with a capital M

```
Math.floor
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the event listener inside the function. The function will only run if you call it, so the event listener will never be added. Additionally, `document.write()` will overwrite the entire page. I changed it to use `document.createElement()` and `document.body.appendChild()`. Change your code to this:

```
function askQuestions(random) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * testQuestions.length);
    var el = document.createElement('p');
    el.textContent = random.toString();
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}

var start = document.getElementById(testStart);
start.addEventListner('click', askQuestions);
```